# Error on add a teacher to a classroom - Failed Precondition

Tags: google-classroom

I've had problems to add teachers to a classroom. The problem happens in specific classrooms and I received a Precondition Error Message.

Request:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/11115612909/teachers' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"userId":"ana.gomes@***"}' \
  --compressed
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Precondition check failed.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

I've already checked all the conditions described in the api reference, but everything is correct (quotas, group numbers, classroom numbers).

Comment: I've Adjusted, tks

Comment: There can be a number of reasons. Our most common one is that the user is disabled in google apps. So the teacher should be in the classroom according to their SIS but their google environment has the teacher account disabled. Google did recently update https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors so maybe that is helpful?